# Implementing Forwarder to Contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

I am using this code for implementing Forwarder in my Contract.

```
contract Forward {

  address public destinationAddress;
  event LogForwarded(address indexed sender, uint amount);
  event LogFlushed(address indexed sender, uint amount);

  constructor() public {
    destinationAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  function() payable public {
    emit LogForwarded(msg.sender, msg.value);
    destinationAddress.transfer(msg.value);
  }

  function flush() public {
    emit LogFlushed(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
    destinationAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

}
```

But it's showing me some errors as I am using Compiler **0.6.0** and this code is of **0.4.23** and I am not able to convert it to latest version. Can someone help me with it?

Here is a preview of the error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type Error: send and transfer are only available for objects of type "address payable " not address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83147/type-error-send-and-transfer-are-only-available-for-objects-of-type-address-pa)

Comment: you may want to inspect the first line of your contract, the one that starts `pragma solidity` - feel free to include it in your code above if the problem persists. Please also include the version whatever tool you're using to compile is using

Answer (score 1):

Changing `address public destinationAddress;` to `address payable public destinationAddress;` worked for me.